# Is there a way to create a 3D map with Highmaps [Highcharts library]

Tags: javascript, highcharts, 3d

I was wondering if there's a way to create a 3D map with Highmaps the same way we do with the charts of the Highcharts library. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: No, it's not possible. Highmaps is 2D map library tool. Highcharts have an option to draw some of the charts in 3D.